# is there a way to perform a look-ahead with fslex/Lexing.LexBuffer

Tags: f#, lexer

I'm using fslex and in one of my tokenizer rules I need to look for the next char so I can decide whether to continue consuming tokens or to stop, unwind and let the previous rule consume it.

I've spent some checking its source code, and looks like the only way would be to compile a version that exposes some internal methods. Maybe someone here has a better solution?

Comment: Don't know if you've gone to far to changed tool but have you thought about using FsParsec instead? I only have limited experince with both fslex and fsparsec, but from what I've seen fsparsec is much better. Not sure if fsparsec supports exactly what you want, but it does say it supports lookahead grammas, so I feel theres a good chance.

Comment: If you really want to use FsLex/FsYacc (which are quite comfortable), "cheating" a bit seems like a good solution. But you should first consider using FsParsec (which was designed especially for this, but it isn't as easy to use).

Comment: One way I've handled that in the past with other lexers and parsers with no lookahead is to implement a custom enumerator wrapper that supports "put-back." The exclusive boundary item can then be put back and re-parsed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe looking at the [source code](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/54799#685032) of LexBuffer can help. Although there are properties (`BufferScanStart` and `BufferScanLength`) to set the position of the lexer in the input stream, those are internal. I'm not sure what would be required to expose those in a safe way.

There is also a question on [HubFS](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/3594.aspx) which deals with putting back. The conclusion seems to be the same: fslex does not currently support it.